# Lock cells dependent on other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an excel where other users can only change a range of cells dependent on an other cell they can change as well (B2). The independent cell B2 is a dropdownlist where they can choose from and can have 4 values. I looked on internet and found examples of independent cells having 2 values. I based myself on this. When I check my code when I didn't protect my worksheet yet it looks like the right cells are locked and unlocked. From the moment I change it to protected sheet I get Run time error 1004:Unable to set locked property of ranged class. I tried to solve it but can't find to fix it. Does someone has an idea where I'm going wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("B2") = "text 1" Then
        Range("F4:Q4").Locked = True
        Range("B2").Locked = False
 ElseIf Range("B2") = "Text 2" Then
         Range("F4:I4").Locked = False
         Range("B2").Locked = False
        Range("J4:Q4").Locked = True
    ElseIf Range("B2") = "Text 3" Then
        Range("B4:Q4").Locked = False
        Range("B2").Locked = False
    ElseIf Range("B2") = "text 4" Then
        Range("B4:Q4").Locked = False
        Range("B2").Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I was able to solve it with following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
If Range("B2") = "Text 1" Then
    Sheet2.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
        Range("F4:Q4").Locked = True
        Range("B2").Locked = False
        Sheet2.Protect Password:="Secret"
 ElseIf Range("B2") = "text 2" Then
 Sheet2.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
         Range("F4:I4").Locked = False
         Range("B2").Locked = False
        Range("J4:Q4").Locked = True
        Sheet2.Protect Password:="Secret"
    ElseIf Range("B2") = "text 3" Then
    Sheet2.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
        Range("B4:Q4").Locked = False
        Range("B2").Locked = False
        Sheet2.Protect Password:="Secret"
    ElseIf Range("B2") = "text 4" Then
    Sheet2.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
        Range("B4:Q4").Locked = False
        Range("B2").Locked = False
        Sheet2.Protect Password:="Secret"
    End If
```

Now I'm trying to put back in code that was also embedded in worksheet_change

```
If Target.Column = 2 Then
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub
```

This gives me error that I have protected sheet. I thought solving it like this.

```
Sheet2.Unprotect Password:="Secret"
If Target.Column = 2 Then
  If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub
Sheet2.Protect Password:="Secret"
```

If I do this it does no longer erase value next to dropdownlist. Any clue why it no longer does this?

Comment: When you protect a sheet all cells are locked by default. To unlock them you have to first unprotect the sheet.

Comment: So after every if I first unlock it, to then lock my sheet at and of if again?

Comment: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm

Comment: I have a follow up question, I put it into my original post. I don't know if it's better to create a new question for this.

Comment: Yes think it might be better as a new question.